# Add one year to the random date selected in java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, date, datepicker

I have two fields start date and end date. I am trying to add one year to the what ever the date selected for start date. Here is my view

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new {id="StartDateId", style="width: 113px;", onblur = "dateformat(this,'MM/DD/YYYY')"})  
       <img src="~/Images/calendar.jpg"  onclick="scwShow(StartDateId,event,'MM/DD/YYYY');return false;" width="17" height="16"/>


@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new {id="EndDateId", style="width: 113px;", onblur = "dateformat(this,'MM-DD-YYYY')" }) 
      <img src="~/Images/calendar.jpg"  onclick="scwShow(EndDateId,event,'MM-DD-YYYY');return false;" width="17" height="16"/>
```

I have written java script like this

```
   $('#StartDateId').focusout(function (Cal) {
         var myDate = new Date(document.getElementById('StartDateId').value);
         var datetime = new Date(date+' '+time);
         // format the output
         var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
         var day = myDate.getDate() - 1;
         var year = myDate.getFullYear() + 1;

         var dateTimeString = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
         alert(dateTimeString);
         $('#EndDateId').val == "";
         $('#EndDateId').val(dateTimeString);

         myDate = myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12); 
         alert(myDate);

         $("#EndDateId").val(myDate);

     });
```

Please help me how to format the time selected. How can I proceed fuerther

Comment: `futureDate = myDate.setFullYear(mydate.getFullYear() + 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding or subtracting month,year w3schools provided the setFullYear() function.
You can directly add or subtract whatever date you want

See example:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the date 1 year ahead of the given date.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() +12);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setfullyear.asp][1]